# Laravel - Redirect from custom class

Tags: php, architecture, laravel-4

How can I redirect application to specific url from my custom class?

Let's say I have my custom class API in Laravel Application:

```
class API {

    private function generic_request( $uri ) 
    {
       $response = $this->getResponse($uri);
       if($response == 'bad_token') 
       {
          //redirect to login screen with message
       }
    }
```

In my controller function:

```
public function add_employee() {
    $data['employee_positions'] = API::generic_request('/employees/position_list');
    $this->layout->content = View::make('employees.add_employee')->with($data);
}
```

I've tried `Events`, but you can't redirect from `Event` listener. Right now I'm using `Exceptions` but I feel like it's wrong approach. For example:

```
App::abort(401);
```

and then in `global.php` :

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    /*CORE API Exceptions*/

    if($code == 401) 
    {
        Session::put('message','System Action: Expired Token');
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create a response and return it all the way back to Laravel:

```
<?php

class API {

    public function doWhatever($uri)
    {
        return $this->generic_request($uri);
    }

    private function generic_request( $uri ) 
    {
       $response = $this->getResponse($uri);

       if($response == 'bad_token') 
       {
          return Redirect::to('login')->with('message', 'your message');
       }

    }

}

Route::get('test', function()
{
    return with(new API)->doWhatever('yourURI');
});
```

Comment: What if make API call in my `controller` function like this: `$data['employee_positions'] = API::generic_request('/employees/position_list'); 
$this->layout->content = View::make('employees.add_employee')->with($data);` ? With your example I will just see json response. I wonder if there is a general approach instead wrapping every request with `if` statements

Comment: On a private and non-static method?

Comment: API should not do redirections, only return responses to requests! Consumer should make decision based on received response. I would just return status code in response headers with some json in body which explains situation.

Comment: His comment says `//redirect to login screen with message`, this doesn't look like an API worflow to me, maybe this is just a badly named class, but I'm not here to jugde architecture, this a primarily opinion based based answer that should be pointed to Programmers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124867/where-should-i-ask-software-architecture-design-questions.

Comment: I have two instances of Laravel that talk to each other as Server-Client. This is an API client class example that receives responses from Server Instance.

Answer (score 2):

With Laravel 5.7 you can use the what @casft originally mentioned like this -

```
abort(redirect('login')->with('alert-warning', 'Your session token has expired. Please login to continue.'));
```

When you are not using the laravel traditional Auth and rely on a bearer tokens for authentication, moreover you want to prevent your public functions from code smell then you can filter on 401 http response call with this handy function. May not be the best or elegant solution but gets the job done.